# Cross-platform way of communcation between processes in C webserver

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, webserver

I made a simple webserver in C now with config implementation. Now, I want to add feature to manage server by calling same process with command line arguments. Like Nginx for example: **nginx -s reload** will send signal to server and it will reload config from file. I want to achieve the same. But how? In Linux, I can send a signal to server master process by getting PID from pidfile. But how to make it in Windows? Or maybe there is another way?

Answer (score 1):

You can listen on a fixed port number with loopback interface for IPC. There are many cross-platform libraries like **libuv** and **nanomsg**.

--

Another method is to use some abstraction provided by a library. For example, still [**libuv**](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/pipe.html) and [**nanomsg**](http://nanomsg.org/v1.0.0/nn_ipc.7.html). (Both use domain socket on Unix and named pipes on Windows.)